# Executing SSIS package from cmd line failed

Tags: ssis, ibm-midrange

I need your help please i'am trying to execute an ssis package from cmd line (the execution in bids works fine) the package has an oledb source that points to an AS400 data base and loads the data Under sql server
i tried to:
1 change the debugging propertise 64 to false
2 used both SQL Server Execute Package Utility 32 and 64

but im having the same error

any idea about the source of this error??[below the error im getting when consulting the all execution report Under SSISDB catalog]

[image]

Comment: Did you install the drivers on the sql server where the ssis package was deployed to and running from? I speculate that there are/were a separate install for the drivers used to connect to the AS400, that would also need to be install on the SQL server. That's usually what that means, it can't find the necessary drivers.

Comment: `The requested OLE DB provider IBMDA4000.DataSource.1 is not registered` ... class not registered as Tim has indicated. The other possibility is that you have multiple versions of dtexec (SQL Server execute package utility) on your machine and you're running a version of dtexec that doesn't have the driver registered